# How many slots do the new research labs in Eve Online have?

Tags: eve-online

I reactivated Eve yesterday and my old POS was still there. So I reactivated it and found out that the modules have changed drastically. I have 1 Research Lab and 1 Designer Lab going, but I can't find the maximum amount of PE/ME/Copy Slots for the hell of it.

What are the new limits for those modules and where can I find my number of personal slots left within the new research window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slots are a thing of the past. With the new industry changes that came a patch or two ago, you have unlimited slots. The only limiting factor is that the more jobs you have running at once, the more expensive each slot becomes.

These days it's also TE (Time Efficiency) rather than PE.

http://community.eveonline.com/news/dev-blogs/eve-industry-all-you-want-to-know/

Comment: Is there a way then to see how busy a station is so you know if it is worth it to research there or not?

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness A bit late, but the cost index is a good indicator. The more people using it, the more expensive the jobs will be based on this index.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness There's an "industry" option in the starmap that will allow you to see the relative cost index of a system. It's my favorite way of finding a good station for manufacturing.